# "Functions are not valid as a React child" during replacement react-router-dom v5 to v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried to solve this problem in several ways without success. This Router work perfect with **render** but when I replace by **element** then the App.jsx throws me an error.

If I delete a **() =>** in Route with **Homepage** than **Homepage** component will be render, but I can't do this in Route with signin/signup.

I can't figure out where the error could be.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./Pages/Homepage/Homepage";
import SignIn from "./Pages/Authentication/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./Pages/Authentication/SignUp";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";

import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const checkAuthenticated = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/auth/verify", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { jwtToken: localStorage.token },
      });

      const parseRes = await res.json();

      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthenticated();
  }, []);

  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? null : (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/signin"
              element={(props) =>
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <SignIn {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/dashboard/overview" />
                )
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/signup"
              element={((props) =>
                !isAuthenticated ? (
                  <SignUp {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/dashboard/overview" />
                )
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={(props) =>
                isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Dashboard {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/signin" />
                )
              }
            />
            <Route exact path="/" element={() => <Homepage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Route` component changed significantly from `react-router-dom@5` to `react-router-dom@6`. There are no longer `component` or `render` or `children` function props, instead replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

```
const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? null : (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              element={!isAuthenticated
                ? <SignIn setAuth={setAuth} />
                : <Navigate to="/dashboard/overview" />
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/signup"
              element={!isAuthenticated
                ? <SignUp setAuth={setAuth} />
                : <Navigate to="/dashboard/overview" />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={isAuthenticated
                ? <Dashboard setAuth={setAuth} />
                : <Navigate to="/signin" />
              }
            />
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Route protection is so common that there is layout route pattern for it. Create layout routes that consume the `isAuthenticated` state and render null or some loading indicator while the authentication status is fetched, then conditionally renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into ***or*** a redirect.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoutes = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, etc..
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/signin" replace />;
}

const AnonymousRoutes = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, etc..
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Navigate to="/dashboard/overview" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
}
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(); // initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthenticated = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/auth/verify", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { jwtToken: localStorage.token },
        });

        const parseRes = await res.json();

        setIsAuthenticated(!!parseRes);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    };

    checkAuthenticated();
  }, []);

  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />}>
          <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn setAuth={setAuth} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp setAuth={setAuth} />} />
        </Route>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />}>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard setAuth={setAuth} />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Note also that because there are no render functions for the routed components that there are no longer any route props (*i.e. `history`, `location`, `match`*). These were replaced by React hooks, i.e. `useNavigate`, `useLocation`, and `useParams`. Use the hooks the components if they need to access these.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! The Homepage component is rendered, but SignIn and SignUp are still not working, they both throw an error **No routes matched location "/dashboard/overview"**. Thank you so much. I will try later again!

Comment: @CollapsingTime I don't see any routes rendering on path `"/dashboard/overview"`, where is this path supposed to be rendered? Of the `Dashboard` component is rendering descendent routes then it should be rendered on `path="/dashboard/*"` to allow descendent path matching.

Comment: Thank you I found a small mistake in SignIn component. It was due to removal first useState hook. Now everything is working.

Comment: @CollapsingTime OK, glad to hear it's working for you now. Cheers and good luck!